# Integrating Branch SDK inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, branch.io

I want to integrate the branch SDK inside a fragment with two options.

1. Enter Referral Code (which should work for the first time only)
2. Your referral code (generating one unique referral code )

Please suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Alex from Branch.io here:

This is probably too broad for a StackOverflow question. It is related to app architecture and is not specifically to implementing the Branch SDK.

I recommend you take a look at the Branch documentation pages [on referral programs](https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/overview/) to get started.